# Why $-\Delta u(x)=-\int_{\mathbb R^d}\nabla _xG(x,y)\cdot \nabla f(y)\mathrm d y=\int_{\mathbb R^d}\nabla _y G(x,y)\cdot \nabla f(y)\mathrm d y$?

Tags: real-analysis, harmonic-analysis, harmonic-functions

Let $$G(r)=\begin{cases}-\frac{1}{2\pi}\ln(r)&d=2\\ \frac{1}{d(d-2)|B_1|r^{d-2}}&d\geq 3\end{cases}$$
the fundamental solution of Laplace equation where $|B_1|$ is the volume of the unit sphere in $\mathbb R^d$. Formally, $$-\nabla G(x,y)=\delta_{x=y}$$
where $G(x,y)= G(|x-y|)$.

*Quest. 1 :* Isn't it strange the notation $G(x,y)= G(|x-y|)$ ? I don't really see what it mean (since in one way $G:\mathbb R^{2d}\longrightarrow \mathbb R$ and and the other $G:\mathbb R\longrightarrow \mathbb R$...

Let $f\in \mathcal C^2(\mathbb R^d)$ compact supported and define $$u(x)=\int_{\mathbb R^d}G(x,y)f(y)\mathrm d y.$$
I'm trying to show that $\Delta u=-f$ is $\mathbb R^d$. In the correction it's written
$$-\Delta u(x)=-\int_{\mathbb R^d}\nabla _xG(x,y)\cdot \nabla f(y)\mathrm d y=\int_{\mathbb R^d}\nabla _y G(x,y)\cdot \nabla f(y)\mathrm d y,$$
but I don't understand those to equality. To me, we only have $$-\Delta u(x)=-\int_{\mathbb R^d} \Delta _x G(x,y)f(y)\mathrm d y.$$

Any idea ?

Comment: $G(x,y)= G(|x-y|)$ is a common abuse of notations. It means $G(x, y) = F(|x-y|)$ for some $F:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$. But one does not want to introduce a new notation $F$ so they also call this $F$ to be $G$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

$$\nabla _x G(x,y)=G'(|x-y|)\nabla _x(|x-y|)=-G'(|x-y|)\nabla _y(|x-y|).$$